# sidebar: to box or not to box?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, sidebar

I don't care for the white boxes on the grey sidebar -- I find that my eye is drawn to the sidebar because the white on grey "vibrates".

I don't think the role of the sidebar is to be quite so in-your-face; I think it looks better with whitespace, just letting **the cool Pixel font** carry the sidebar by itself with no extra eye-vibrating fluff:

[image]

Your thoughts?

Comment: I don't have a strong preference either way. I only added the curved borders around the sidebar sections because that style reminds me of some old school games' styling. I feel this detail makes the site "gamey." However if it becomes a usability issue i'll remove it.

Comment: What if the color were simply a dark grey instead of white? It'd match the header + footer in that case as well.

Comment: I feel like I'm at the eye doctor: "Number 1 or Number 2?"

Comment: If nothing else it should be more _pixelated._ :D

Comment: Data point: I didn't even notice the boxes, or their absence, until I noticed a link to this question under the Visit Meta heading.

Answer (score 5):

I like the boxes, I think they make the sidebar look less cluttered.

Though that might just be the *put-everything-into-groupboxes* winforms-programmer side of me speaking.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the sidebar does look better without those borders. However, looking at your mock-up I think that the margins between the two boxes should be decreased without the borders, since right now it has padding towards the border and a margin between borders.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a possible third way, Horizontal lines between the groups (`border-bottom` on `.module` for example.)

[image: mockup]